# angularjs module not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS. I am trying to list out the variable in controller. I have this in the script.

```
var demoController = angular.module('sampleController',[]);

demoController.controller('sampleController', function ($scope){
    $scope.customers=[
        {name:'John Smith', country:'Denmark', worth:'5000000'},
        {name:'John Lewis',country:'England',worth:'10000000'},
        {name:'Rick Evans',country:'America',worth:'6000000'}
    ];
});
```

And I have this in the HTML.

```
<html ng-app="demoController">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <body>
        <h1>Applying filters</h1>
        <div ng-controller="sampleController">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.country }} - {{ cust.worth | currency:"$":2 }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is not listing out the variable. What is wrong with this script. Thanks!!

Comment: ng-app="demoController" when angular.module('sampleController',[]); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define your module in the right way

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
```

Then, use it in your HTML file

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

See it working on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/motopi/1/edit?html,js,output)

> Note that, the angular module's name is the one defined within the quotes
>
> `angular.module('app',[]);`
>
> So, if you wrote `var xModule = angular.module('app2',[]);` your module name is `app2` not `xModule`

Comment: Including that empty array is key (as opposed to passing in the module name as the only argument).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I am using :

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html data-ng-app="app">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script> 
<body>
<h1>Applying filters</h1>
<div data-ng-controller="sampleController">
<ul><li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.country }} - {{ cust.worth | currency:"$":2 }}</li></ul>
</div>

<script id="jsbin-javascript">var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('sampleController', function ($scope){
    $scope.customers=[
        {name:'John Smith', country:'Denmark', worth:'5000000'},
        {name:'John Lewis',country:'England',worth:'10000000'},
        {name:'Rick Evans',country:'America',worth:'6000000'}
    ];
});
</script> 
</body></html>
```

And the output is :

```
Applying filters
{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.country }} - {{ cust.worth | currency:"$":2 }}
```

Let me know what is missing here.